# CONTACT в выборке

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, ' ', otch_name)
```

Возможно ли применить данную конструкцию в выборке к примеру

```
where CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, ' ', otch_name) != 'name1 name2 name3'
```

Comment: А проверить самостоятельно?) Да, можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name, ' ', otch_name) преобразуется в строку и будет сравниваться с другой строкой на неравенство.

Важно: NULL значения тоже не попадут в выборку